# WakefulBroadcastReceiver With FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I trying to use push notifications using FCM.

My question:
Why is the method `onReceive` not be called in `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` while the app is closed?  It is called when the app in the background or foreground.

But it does work using GCM. `onReceive` is called while the app is closed, in the background or foreground.